# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization;

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, html, popup

I'm developing a page and I import another page with popups on it using `@Html.Partial("AddCommentPopup")` and on pages where I am using an `<a href="#pupupIDhere" data-rel="popup etc..>` It works perfectly fine. On this page I need to do it differently though because of the way JQM works with links. So I'm using 
`<div onclick="console.log('divclicked');$('#statusUpdate').popup('open');">`. And the console tells me that it is being clicked, but it doesn't open the popup and throws this error: 
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you recently just update jquery?

Comment: No. Not in the last couple of months.

Comment: Which popup plugin are you using?

Comment: Just whatever the JQM default is for pop ups.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try initializing the div as a popup first, then open it...

```
<div onclick="console.log('divclicked');
    $('#statusUpdate').popup();
    $('#statusUpdate').popup('open');">
</div>
```

Comment: that does work, but is that good design? Seems that the library should detect this and do the "right" thing

Comment: @IcedDante - Talk to John Resig

Comment: Works puuuurr-fectly! go gabe!

Answer (score 7):

[like  this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131431/jquery-mobile-1-3-1-uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-popup-prior-to-initia) i did and worked fine for me

```
 $("#statusUpdate").popup();
$("#statusUpdate").popup('open')
```

you have to initialize it before opening  it

Comment: how is this different from the accepted answer (that is months older than this) ?

Answer (score 0):

yeah,it's useful ,
$('#statusUpdate').popup();

$('#statusUpdate').popup('open');

$('#statusUpdate').popup(); /* this this for initialization*/

$('#statusUpdate').popup('open'); /*this for operation*/